# Loading picture Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to coding and having some difficulties with the below error message.

Using rails I have created an edit profile page where you can add a range of information about yourself, save and display it. The form works fine but has an issue when loading a profile picture. It allows you to pick a picture, However when you go to save the form the forbidden attributes error comes up. I know it has to do with my `EditprofilesController` and the `param` settings. I just can not work out what param code is required to allow the picture to be saved and displayed on the webpage. Below is the code in question. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
def create
        @editprofile = Editprofile.new (params[:editprofile])
    if @editprofile.save
        redirect_to editprofiles_path 
    end
```

My code is on Github if that helps.

https://github.com/blackops11/Pinteresting1

Below is the full error message

```
ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError in EditprofilesController#create
ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError

Extracted source (around line #14):

13 def create
14   @editprofile = Editprofile.new (params[:editprofile])
15 if @editprofile.save
16   redirect_to editprofiles_path 
17 end
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you copy/pasted the error message in its entirety.

Comment: Hi Josh, Error message has been added above.

Answer (score 0):

In rails4 you should sanitize parameters before passing to model:

```
@editprofile = Editprofile.new( params.require(:editprofile).permit(:some_param, :some_other_param) )
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, really appreciate it. I added the code below and it has come up with undefined method for save fro Nil :Nilclass?                                              def create
  Editprofile.new( params.require(:editprofile).permit(:image) )
  if @editprofile.save
  redirect_to editprofiles_path 
 end
 end

Comment: this is because you did not assign the above to variable `@editprofile`

Answer (score 0):

This may helpful:-

```
def create
    @editprofile = Editprofile.new(editprofile_params)
    if @editprofile.save
        redirect_to editprofiles_path 
    end
end

private

def editprofile_params
    params.require(:editprofile).permit(:image)
end
```